# NameError: uninitialized constant MongoClient

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm using Ruby 2.2. I have installed `mongo` gem, but still get the error:

```
MY-MAC:ruby-2.2.0 me$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bson (4.0.3)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
log4r (1.1.10)
mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
minitest (5.4.3)
mongo (2.2.3)
nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.0.8)
MY-MAC:ruby-2.2.0 me$ irb
2.2.0 :001 > require 'mongo'
 => true
2.2.0 :002 > include Mongo
 => Object
2.2.0 :003 > Mongo::VERSION
 => "2.2.3"
2.2.0 :004 > c = MongoClient.new
NameError: uninitialized constant MongoClient
    from (irb):4
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.2.0 :005 >
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object you want to instantiate is `Mongo::Client.new`

[Docs are here.](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/#creating-a-client)